# Winform C# events not working after applying MetroFramework UI

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, metroframework

I installed MetroFramework in my project, but events are not working.

```cs
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Text = "Test";
        }


        private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.Blue;
            this.Text = "click";
        }
    }
}
```

this is my Form1.cs file, and Form1_Click function working randomly. (Click event)
Form1_Load function is working. the application title is 'Test'.

when I change code `MetroFramework.Form.MetroForm` to 'Form', It works well.

.Net version = 4.7.2
MetroFramework version = 1.2.0.3

when i click the form window, change the window backColor and Text

Comment: Where is your `EventHandler` for `Form1_Click` ?

Comment: Don't debug by setting text on the form. Use the debugger properly, i.e. set breakpoints on the relevant lines of code. If you do that are you saying that the breakpoint gets hit sometimes when you click the form but not others?

Comment: at Form1.designer.cs, there is EventHandler like below

`this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);`
`this.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Click);`
But It's not working yet,,,